# Why is using MYSQL_PWD considered insecure? I thought environment variables were private, unlike command-line arguments

Tags: mysql, docker, shell, environment-variables

In [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/environment-variables.html), it said that use of `MYSQL_PWD` is extremely insecure because other users can inspect the environment of a running process, and thus this feature is deprecated. I thought environment variables were private to the user (and root), unlike command-line arguments, which are public. I assumed this was also why most official Docker images can be configured through environment variables. If this feature is removed, it would be rather inconvenient for using the MySQL shell of the official Docker image when a script is passed on standard input and the credentials cannot be leaked on the command-line (out of scope for this question)

Are environment variables visible to other users? Should credentials only ever be transferred as files?

Comment: Use the `-E` option to `ps` to see the environment of the processes.

Comment: That is private to the user though; other users only see command-line arguments.

Comment: Consider [security.se] as a more focused place for this question.

Answer (score 0):

I think the documentation is pretty clear on the reasons:

> Use of MYSQL_PWD to specify a MySQL password must be considered extremely insecure and should not be used. Some versions of ps include an option to display the environment of running processes. On some systems, if you set MYSQL_PWD, your password is exposed to any other user who runs ps. Even on systems without such a version of ps, it is unwise to assume that there are no other methods by which users can examine process environments.

Comment: That's true of **old** systems -- it was commonly the case when I started in the 90s, but it's no longer true today and hasn't been for quite some time. On modern systems that information is only exposed to the same user or the superuser; so this documentation is sorely outdated.